# different definitions of string changes answer

Tags: c++, c++11

I've started learning C++ from HackerRank.

st.first_name outputs concatenated strings(first_name and last_name) when they are defined like char first_name[50]; and  char last_name[50];. But when i define them like string first_name; and string last_name; output is fine. Why is it so?

Here is the code:

```
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;

    /*
        add code for struct here.
    */
    struct Student
    {
        int age;
        //char first_name[50];
        //char last_name[50];
        string first_name;
        string last_name;
        int standard;
    };

    int main() {
        Student st;

        cin >> st.age >> st.first_name >> st.last_name >> st.standard;
        cout << st.age << " " << st.first_name << " " << st.last_name << " " << st.standard;

        return 0;
    }
```

Here is the link to this question on HackerRank:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-struct

input for which i'm getting contradicting output:
11 
lwpxiteeppsacowpnbxluqpmasgnwefzcsvrjxxammuqcftzgn uinkydgppulchupyrlwvbisdtqurfcsbaobgtplvvlxbxgltk
10

expected output: 
11 
lwpxiteeppsacowpnbxluqpmasgnwefzcsvrjxxammuqcftzgn uinkydgppulchupyrlwvbisdtqurfcsbaobgtplvvlxbxgltk 
10

my output: 11 lwpxiteeppsacowpnbxluqpmasgnwefzcsvrjxxammuqcftzgnuinkydgppulchupyrlwvbisdtqurfc‌​sbaobgtplvvlxbxgltk 
uinkydgppulchupyrlwvbisdtqurfcsbaobgtplvvlxbxgltk 
10

Comment: I ran your code and did not get concatenated output. I cannot access the link to your input. Can you verify and put up input & result?

Comment: Please *copy and paste* the actual input you give the program into the body of the question. Also please include, as plain text, the expected **and** the actual output of the program.

Comment: It gave false output on the hackerrank ide

Comment: input:11
lwpxiteeppsacowpnbxluqpmasgnwefzcsvrjxxammuqcftzgn
uinkydgppulchupyrlwvbisdtqurfcsbaobgtplvvlxbxgltk
10

Comment: expected output: 11 lwpxiteeppsacowpnbxluqpmasgnwefzcsvrjxxammuqcftzgn uinkydgppulchupyrlwvbisdtqurfcsbaobgtplvvlxbxgltk 10

Comment: my output: 11 lwpxiteeppsacowpnbxluqpmasgnwefzcsvrjxxammuqcftzgnuinkydgppulchupyrlwvbisdtqurfcsbaobgtplvvlxbxgltk uinkydgppulchupyrlwvbisdtqurfcsbaobgtplvvlxbxgltk 10

Comment: You entered 50 characters, your buffer is only 50 `char`s long, so there is no terminating `\0`, which means on output the following memory is also read. Your problem is basically a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ C-style strings (using arrays of `char`) need a special *terminator* character, `'\0'`. This of course take up a character and you need to include that in the array you allocate. If you don't have space for the terminator it will be written out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*.

That's why you really should use `std::string` when programming in C++, you don't risk buffer overflows.

***If*** you need to use C-style strings and arrays of `char` you need to add an extra character to your arrays to make space for the terminator. So if you want to allow the users to enter 50 characters, then you need an array of 51 characters. But beware, C++ has no bounds-checking so if the user enters a string longer than 50 characters you will still write out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks,  it really helped.

Comment: In C++ style string declaration, we don't need to define the number of characters the string will be holding, and that's why there's no problem of buffer overflow. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @DivyanshuSingh [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is *dynamic*, it will grow when needed. So no problems when using it.